# Past perfect form of should

Tags: past-tense

I have encountered a sentence ,which I’m not sure about.
This passage is about two people talking in the past. One of them is telling a story that happened before the time these two people met, so story is in past perfect.
The part I struggled is this sentence: “... Only later did they learn that corpse should have been kept for identification purposes...” I couldn’t understand why this is ‘should have been kept.’ Because it’s past perfect, I thought it should have been in past perfect. So how do we use should in past perfect?

Comment: I don't like that ***so story is in past perfect*** bit. Native speakers don't like to *overuse* Perfect forms, so in practice even if your "past within the past" story *starts* with (one, or a few) instances of the Perfect, it would tend to revert to Simple Past quite quickly. For some reason, non-native speakers like English Perfect forms much more than the actual natives.

Comment: The only way you can get further back than 'should have been kept' is with 'should, even earlier, have been kept'.